# Addressing multiple levels in JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

I use jQuery $.get to bring over some json data out of php. It looks like this:

```
[{
    "itemNumber_1": "1",
    "partNumber_1": "U1234567890-XYZ",
    "description_1": "front label",
    "artworkFee_1": "35.00",
    "expediteDelivery_1": "55.00",
    "height_1": "1.27",
    "width_1": "5.05",
    "edgeColorNumber_1": "3",
    "pmsColorNumber_1": "0",
    "cutoutNumber_1": "5",
    "adhesiveFreeNumber_1": "0",
    "clearWindowNumber_1": "0",
    "barcodeNumber_1": "0",
    "serialNumber_1": "0",
    "replaceablesNumber_1": "0",
    "yAxisSpacing_1": "0.10",
    "xAxisSpacing_1": "0.10",
    "borderSpacing_1": "0.10",
    "scrapFactor_1": "5.00"
},
{
    "itemNumber_2": "2",
    "partNumber_2": "1234567890-ABC",
    "description_2": "back label",
    "artworkFee_2": "0.00",
    "expediteDelivery_2": "0.00",
    "height_2": "1.25",
    "width_2": "4.00",
    "edgeColorNumber_2": "2",
    "pmsColorNumber_2": "1",
    "cutoutNumber_2": "2",
    "adhesiveFreeNumber_1": "1",
    "clearWindowNumber_2": "1",
    "barcodeNumber_1": "0",
    "serialNumber_2": "0",
    "replaceablesNumber_2": "0",
    "yAxisSpacing_2": "0.10",
    "xAxisSpacing_2": "0.10",
    "borderSpacing_2": "0.10",
    "scrapFactor_2": "5.00"
}]
```

I'm trying to loop through it similar to looping through a 2 dimensional array, but it fails when I use a variable key [i] rather than a hard coded numeric key [1].

```
function useExistingQuoteToFillForm(){   
    $.get('includes/getQuoteSessionVariables.php', function(response){  
    var js_JSONobject = JSON.parse(response); 

    $("#1 input[name='width_1']").attr("value", js_JSONobject[0]['width_1'] );
    $("#1 input[name='height_1']").attr('value', js_JSONobject[0]['height_1']);
    $("#1 input[name='artworkSetup_1']").attr('value', js_JSONobject[0]['artworkSetup_1']);
    $("#1 input[name='expedite_1']").attr('value', js_JSONobject[0]['expedite_1']);
    $("#1 input[name='partNumber_1']").attr('value', js_JSONobject[0]['partNumber_1']);
    $("#1 input[name='description_1']").attr('value', js_JSONobject[0]['description_1']);
    $("#1 select[name='lexan_1']" ).val( js_JSONobject[0]['lexan_1'] );
    $("#1 select[name='vinyl_1']" ).val( js_JSONobject[0]['vinyl_1'] );
    $("#1 select[name='polyester_1']" ).val( js_JSONobject[0]['polyester_1'] );
    $("#1 select[name='xAxisSpacing_1']").val(js_JSONobject[0]['xAxisSpacing_1']);
    $("#1 select[name='yAxisSpacing_1']").val(js_JSONobject[0]['yAxisSpacing_1']);
    $("#1 select[name='borderSpacing_1']").val(js_JSONobject[0]['borderSpacing_1']);
    $("#1 select[name='scrapFactor_1']").val(js_JSONobject[0]['scrapFactor_1']);
    $("#1 select[name='colors_1']").val(js_JSONobject[0]['edgeColorNumber_1']);
    $("#1 select[name='colorMatch_1']").val(js_JSONobject[0]['pmsColorNumber_1']);
    $("#1 select[name='cutOut_1']").val(js_JSONobject[0]['cutOutNumber_1']);
    $("#1 select[name='seeThru_1']").val(js_JSONobject[0]['seeThruNumber_1']);
    $("#1 select[name='barCode_1']").val(js_JSONobject[0]['barCodeNumber_1']);
    $("#1 select[name='serialNumbers_1']").val(js_JSONobject[0]['serialNumbers_1']);
    $("#1 select[name='replaceable_1']").val(js_JSONobject[0]['replaceablesNumber_1']);
    $("#1 select[name='adhesiveFree_1']").val(js_JSONobject[0]['adhesiveFree_1']);
    // end panel 1

    // if more than one item panel
    if ( Object.keys(js_JSONobject).length > 1) {
        // loop thru object for item panel data
        for(var i = 1; i < Object.keys(js_JSONobject).length; i++){
            var y = i + 1; 

            addItem();
            setTimeout( function(){ // needs a small delay while the new panel comes up
                // this hardcoded numeric key works
                $("#" + y + " input[name='width_" + y + "']").attr("value", js_JSONobject[1]['width_'+ y]); 
                // when I switch to using a variable key it fails to proceed
                $("#" + y + " input[name='height_'" + y + "']").attr('value', js_JSONobject[i]['height_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " input[name='artworkSetup_'" + y + "']").attr('value', js_JSONobject[i]['artworkSetup_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " input[name='expedite_'" + y + "']").attr('value', js_JSONobject[i]['expedite_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " input[name='partNumber_'" + y + "']").attr('value', js_JSONobject[i]['partNumber_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " input[name='description_'" + y + "']").attr('value', js_JSONobject[i]['description_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " select[name='lexan_'" + y + "']").val( js_JSONobject[i]['lexan_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " select[name='vinyl_'" + y + "']").val( js_JSONobject[i]['vinyl_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " select[name='polyester_'" + y + "']").val( js_JSONobject[i]['polyester_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " select[name='xAxisSpacing_'" + y + "']").val(js_JSONobject[i]['xAxisSpacing_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " select[name='yAxisSpacing_'" + y + "']").val(js_JSONobject[i]['yAxisSpacing_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " select[name='borderSpacing_'" + y + "']").val(js_JSONobject[i]['borderSpacing_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " select[name='scrapFactor_'" + y + "']").val(js_JSONobject[i]['scrapFactor_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " select[name='colors_'" + y + "']").val(js_JSONobject[i]['edgeColorNumber_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " select[name='colorMatch_'" + y + "']").val(js_JSONobject[i]['pmsColorNumber_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " select[name='cutOut_'" + y + "']").val(js_JSONobject[i]['cutOutNumber_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " select[name='seeThru_'" + y + "']").val(js_JSONobject[i]['seeThruNumber_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " select[name='barCode_'" + y + "']").val(js_JSONobject[i]['barCodeNumber_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " select[name='serialNumbers_'" + y + "']").val(js_JSONobject[i]['serialNumbers_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " select[name='replaceable_'" + y + "']").val(js_JSONobject[i]['replaceablesNumber_' + y]);
                $("#" + y + " select[name='adhesiveFree_'" + y + "']").val(js_JSONobject[i]['adhesiveFree_' + y ]);
                }, 3000 );
        }
    } 
});
```

}

Obviously, I'm new at this and I'm failing to understand something. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Hm... What is the exact error message? Thx for info.

Please check your function scope in the setTimeout parameter. It seems the function that you give to setTimeout does not have the vars i,y,js_JSONobject in its scope, so you should state

```
setTimeout ( function(i,y,js_JSONobject) { ... }  ,3000 )
```

Comment: -Ve vote. This is not an answer. Consider commenting instead of answers for basic query.

Answer (score 1):

So, the main problem is actually on calling function inside timeout. It won't work because your `i` variable is now something else when the execution time come. To make it work you should call the function with different way :

```
...
(function(js_JSONobject, i){   // I add this before timeout.
    setTimeout(function(){
       ... // The rest of your code.
    }, 3000);
})(js_JSONobject, i);          // and this after timeout.
....
```

Comment: The error message was js_JSONobject[i] was undefined. This solved my problem, thank you